Swing JFrame Icons Not Loading When Called from Another Class (Please ignore my naming conventions xD) (Netbeans, openjdk 20.0.2 64-bit)
I am working on a Java project for a school-related Task, and I'm experiencing an issue when it comes to loading icon images onto JButtons.
So, to start, when I run my JFrame Form directly in the file, right-clicking in the IDE and running just the file it works as intended:
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

                new CardGameFrameForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

To describe the elements that relate to the problem, a grid of 8x8 JButtons are laid out. Initially, the center 2x2 are enabled while the rest are disabled. As the game goes on it becomes 4x4, 6x6 and 8x8.
The idea is that this is a memory make sets of cards.
How it works is that when I click a JButton, the button is disabled.
I have
private static final iconAssigner iconAss = new iconAssigner();
In my constructor, I call levelIncrimenter();
The important part, in regards to this issue, in levelIncrimenter is setCurrentBoard(rowOfCards);
public void setCurrentBoard(int sets) {

        int buttonCount = (sets * sets);
        for (int x = 0; x < buttonCount; x++) {
            currentsetOfButtons[x].setEnabled(true);
            currentsetOfButtons[x].addActionListener(buttonClickListener);

        }
        randomizer(buttonCount);
    }

This just sets the cards that needs to be enabled to being enabled, then randomizes another array for icon placement.
When a button is clicked, the eventListener calls private void flipCard(JButton in)
The flipCard Method will find the index of the button and do the following:
in.setDisabledIcon(iconAss.getSetImage2(randomArray[buttonIndex]));

in.setEnabled(false);

This makes it so that when the button is disabled, it shows the image.
To reiterate, the file works exactly as expected when I directly run the file. However, I want to start my program from a login screen. So, we start here:
public class CardGameJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
         new LoginScreen().setVisible(true); 
    }
}

The loginScreen loads, logic is done for checking my MS database for login info. If everything checks out, I call goToGameScreen();
private void goToGameScreen(){ 
        CardGameFrameForm cardGameFrameForm = new CardGameFrameForm();
        cardGameFrameForm.getCurrentPlayerGamerTag(gamerTagTextField.getText());
        this.setVisible(false);
        cardGameFrameForm.setVisible(true);
    }

I create a new instance of cardGameFrameForm. I pull the GamerTag for later use, I set LoginScreen's visibility to false. Then load the cardGameFrameForm.
However, now when I click the buttons, the icons do not appear. The logic of them being grouped into sets still works. Just the icons don't.
I have tried passing the IconAssinger from the start of the program, which didn't work either.
As a comment suggested, I created a minimal reproducible example.
public class ReproduceMinexampleForCardGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FirstFrameForm().setVisible(true);
    }
}

FirstFrameForm:
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        SecondFrameForm sec = new SecondFrameForm();
        sec.setVisible(true);
    }     

SecondFrameForm:
     imageAssigner iconAss = new imageAssigner();
    
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            jButton1.setDisabledIcon(iconAss.getIcon(2));
            
            jButton1.setEnabled(false);
}

ImageAssigner:
private ImageIcon AcheronIcon, ArgentiIcon, ArlanIcon, AstaIcon, AventurineIcon;
 
 public imageAssigner(){
     createIcons();
 }
 
 private void createIcons(){
    AcheronIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("./images/Character_Acheron_Icon.png"));
    ArgentiIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("./images/Character_Argenti_Icon.png"));
    ArlanIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("./images/Character_Arlan_Icon.png"));
    AstaIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("./images/Character_Asta_Icon.png"));
    AventurineIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("./images/Character_Aventurine_Icon.png"));
 }

  public ImageIcon getIcon(int in){
     
  List<ImageIcon> icons = new ArrayList<>();
     
    icons.add(AcheronIcon);
    icons.add(ArgentiIcon);
    icons.add(ArlanIcon);
    icons.add(AstaIcon);
    icons.add(AventurineIcon);
    
    resizeIcons(icons);
    
  return icons.get(in);
 }
 
public void resizeIcons(List<ImageIcon> icons) {
    for (int i = 0; i < icons.size(); i++) {
        ImageIcon icon = icons.get(i);
        Image resizedImage = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        icons.set(i, new ImageIcon(resizedImage));
    }
}

    


probably the icons are being searched on the wrong directory, but that code is apparently not posted... actually instead of a whole bunch of code snippets, better include ONE [mre]

@user85421 I am creating a minimal example. Should I create a new Post when I'm done?

Okay, I have made the changes. Still getting the described issue above it.

With a bit of tinkering, I seems that if I run my loginScreen form, instead of creating a new instance of the loginscreen in a call I wanted as my main, it works correctly...

fyi, it's 'increment' not 'incriment'

Why are you using "./"? Just use "/" to start searching the directories on your class path. Also, use ImageIO to load the images. You will get an error message if the file is not found.

Maybe this will help: Match Game

What output is produced if you add System.out.println(getClass().getResource("./images/Character_Acheron_Icon.png"));?

As a side note, it’s horribly inefficient, to create a list of all icons, scale all images of all icons, to return one of them, repeating the entire process for each requested icon. If you need scaled versions of all images anyway, create the scaled versions right in the createIcons() method, followed by creating a List of them. Then, use e.g. public ImageIcon getIcon(int in) { return scaledIcons.get(in); }. There’s also no need to call setDisabledIcon each time before you call setEnabled(false). Do it once, when you create the button.
